# Does dynamic_cast require virtual function?

Tags: c++

For example:

```
class Animal
{
    virtual void dummy() {};         //LINE1
}

class Cat : public Animal
{

}

Animal* a = new Cat();
if (Cat* c = dynamic_cast<Cat*> (a))  //LINE2
{
     //Do something.
}
```

If I remove LINE1 from the Animal class (i.e. Animal class does not contain virtual members), LINE2 will not work.

Comment: A class is only polymorphic if it has a virtual member.

Comment: BTW, a class intended to be polymorphic really should have a virtual destructor.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes it does, as per the standard, `dynamic_cast` can only downcast polymorphic types (i.e. a type with at least one virtual function)

Answer (score 9):

`dynamic_cast` can cast to the same class or base class without virtual members. But for downcasting or casting to `void*` (which yields a pointer to the most derived class object) `dynamic_cast` requires a polymorphic class, per C++11 §5.2.7/6:

> “Otherwise, `v` shall be a pointer to or an lvalue of a polymorphic type”

where `v` is the argument you supply.

A polymorphic class is one that has one or more virtual member functions, §10.3/1:

> “A class that declares or
>   inherits a virtual function is called a polymorphic class.”