# error in using dynamic_cast and constructor

Tags: c++, constructor, dynamic-cast

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class myclass {
public:
    int a;
    myclass() : a(-1){};
 };
class derivedclass : public myclass {
     public: 
     int b;
    derivedclass() : b(-2) {};
  };

int main()
{
myclass* p= new myclass;
//  derivedclass* pd = dynamic_cast<derivedclass*>(p);
derivedclass* pd = static_cast<derivedclass*>(p);
cout << pd->b << endl;

return 0;
}
```

I have two questions.

1. `dynamic_cast` is not working. So need to add a virtual function in
   `myclass`?
2. why `pd->b` is not `-2` as is initialized in the
   constructor?

Comment: An instance of `myclass` never could become an instance of `derivedclass` magically.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ is right.  dynamic_cast is for casting a base class pointer to a derived class pointer.  But the pointed to object must be a derived class.  Try `myclass* p= new derivedclass; derivedclass* pd = dynamic_cast<myclass*>(p);`

Answer (score 2):

The `dynamic_cast` is not working for two reasons.

One is that, as you guessed, [you need virtual functions for `dynamic_cast` to work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23945043/does-dynamic-cast-require-virtual-function), which is to say that the base type `myclass` must be polymorphic.

The other reason also addresses your second question. In your code, `derivedclass` inherits from `myclass`. This implies that any object of type `derivedclass` is also an object of type `myclass`. It does **not** imply that any object of type `myclass` is necessarily also of type `derivedclass`, which you seem to be assuming.

```
// creates a new instance of myclass, NOT an instance of derivedclass
myclass* p= new myclass;

// assuming myclass is polymorphic, returns a type-safe pointer to a derivedclass object
// if p is not such an object, returns nullptr, which is useful for error checking
derivedclass* pd1 = dynamic_cast<derivedclass*>(p);

// this is very unsafe! pd2 is now a 'wild' pointer to an object that doesn't exist
derivedclass* pd2 = static_cast<derivedclass*>(p);

// this is Undefined Behavior: there is no such `b` in memory at pd2, and that memory
// is not yours to read from
cout << pd2->b << endl;
```

The reason that `pd->b` is not `-2` is because the constructor of `derivedclass` *never ran*. You never created an object of `derivedclass`.

Answer (score 1):

> dynamic_cast is not working. So need to add a virtual function in derivedclass?

Yes. You do need to have a virtual function in order to use dynamic cast.

Also, you must check whether dynamic cast results in a null pointer. In this case, it would result in null (if there was a virtual function), since `p` does not point to an instance of `derivedclass`.

> why pd->b is not -2 as is initialized in the constructor?

The behaviour is undefined. No `derivedclass` or its members was ever constructed.

Comment: the constructor of myclass initializes >>>`a`<<< to -1.  `b` doesn't exist